# validation errors for process import

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to upload my custom process but got the following vail issue. I have tried to found on this web page but can not found the error code on that page. are there someone can help me resolved this issue? the details  information as below:
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiJUX.png)

Comment: This process is an inherited process. and I am the administrator of this project.

Comment: reference this url:  https://deepakkhare.azurewebsites.net/azure-devops-update-hosted-xml-process/

Comment: The error message is explicitly stating the problem. What trouble are you having correcting the problem?

Comment: Yes, I know the error message explicitly stating the problem, but I don't know how to change the group, I am the project collection administrator.

Comment: Do you have `for="[project] group"` or something similar in the xml?

Comment: Do you use any custom group in your custom process template? It seems has nothing to do with your identity as a project collect administrator. As I check our code, I found that we do not allow any custom group used in custom process template. You can check your file and modify your template. Then upload it again.

Comment: @Joey.Qiao. How about this issue now? Have you check your custom process template? Does it resolved now? If not, you can share your latest info here.